# Rails with ReactJS. What are the benefits?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I am in the middle of creating an admin panel inside my app and I want to be able to add/ remove/ edit items without refreshing the page. The first thing I thought of was AJAX. So I implemented it and it runs pretty well.

What I had to do is to manually remove the proper `div` after deleting an item, add `div` after creating one etc.

After a while I read about ReactJS (heard about it before, but never used it), and about things it can do - especially fetching the DB and updating the view (but only the things that changed). My question is - do I need this?

What are the benefits of using a library like react in this situation?

PS I really find it difficult to get my head around all those things that are available, ready for me to use, since I started my journey with RoR not so long ago. Any tips?

Comment: "What are the benefits of using react here" - you mean, besides not having to manually manage divs? Is that not enough?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience React works fine with Rails and it will allow you to componentize your front end solution keep in mind that you will need to learn Flux too and if you decide to go through this path I suggest to start integrating React-Flux with rails using one of [this 3 ways](http://www.openmindedinnovations.com/blogs/3-ways-to-integrate-ruby-on-rails-react-flux) to do that.

Anyways I think that for your problem the best and cheaper solution (in terms of learning curve) should be using turbolinks.
Check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWEts0rlezA) it will provide you a clear idea of turbolinks advantages.

The solution that you described could be builded using the next steps:

Create a controller for your resource (projects in my case):

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_projects, only: :index

  def index
    @project = Project.new
  end

  private

  def set_projects
    @projects = Projects.all
  end
end
```

Move the project lists to a partial:

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Name
  %tbody
    - projects.each do |project|
      %tr
        %td= project.name
```

Move the creation form to another partial and set it as remote:

```
= form_for project, remote: true do |form|
  = form.text_field :name
  = form.submit :save
```

In the index view render the partials:

```
.new-project-container
  = render 'path_to_my_new_project', project: @project
.project-list-container
  = render 'path_to_my_listed_projects_partial', projects: @projects
```

Add a create endpoint to your controller

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_projects, only: :index

  def index
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    format.js do
      Project.create(project_params)
      set_projects
    end
  end

  private

  def set_projects
    @projects = Projects.all
  end

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

Create a view on /app/views/projects/create.js.erb

```
$('.new-project-container').html("<%= j render 'path_to_my_listed_projects_partial', project: Project.new%>")
$('.project-list-container').html("<%= j render 'path_to_my_listed_projects_partial', projects: @projects%>")
```

This will add your created project to the list automatically for delete feature you can use the same way to think.

Add the remote true to destroy links:

```
%table
  %thead
    %tr
      %th Name
      %th
  %tbody
    - projects.each do |project|
      %tr
        %td= project.name
        %td= link_to :delete, project, method: :delete, remote: true
```

Create an endpoint that responds to JS format for it:

```
  def destroy
    format.js do
      project = Project.find(params[:id])
      project.destroy
      set_projects
    end
  end
```

And the destroy.js.erb

```
$('.project-list-container').html("<%= j render 'path_to_my_listed_projects_partial', projects: @projects%>")
```

I think that this way is cleaner that yours.